# Three.js : Sprites clickable

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, sprite

I have added an array of sprite to the scene in three.js
Is it possible that on click of any sprite information about the sprite is shown?
Like a marker with information on hover or on click?
Something like the photosphere viewer marker
Eg: https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/markers.html.

Comment: yes, it is possible that on click of any sprite information about the sprite is shown.

Comment: Sadly enough, as far as I remember, you cannot raycast sprites. I think because they are not drawn like geometries. You could use a `PlaneGeometry` and then raycast it.

Comment: @somethinghere Raycasting with sprites is possible since `R94`: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_raycast_sprite.html

Comment: @Mugen87 awesome!